# Why doesn't my lane find appicon when running fastlane?

Tags: react-native, fastlane

I have set up a lane for creating icons for the iOS as follows.

```
  desc "Creating iOS icons"
  lane :icon do
    appicon(
      appicon_image_file: 'AppIcon/logo-1024.png',
      appicon_devices: [:ipad, :iphone, :ios_marketing, :watch, :watch_marketing],
      appicon_path: 'vahingonsattuessa/Images'
    )
  end
```

For some reason this does not work and results on error.
[image]

I have also the Pluginfile inside the fastlane folder that has the `gem 'fastlane-plugin-appicon'` inside there.

Android gemfile.lock has the plugin

[image]

And ios gemfile.lock doesn't have plugin for some reason

[image]

both gemfiles has following:

```
plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

Anyone know what I can do the get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was no zero-width space characters. However running `bundle exec fastlane plugin_updates` -> `bundle exec fastlane add_plugin appicon` added appicon to the gemfile.lock file in ios folder now. And everything is working now fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the first plugin in the project and you were asked if you wanted the plugin configuration to be added to Gemfile automatically. Since you answered no, you are missing the plugin configuration.

Add

```
plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

to the Gemfile

Comment: I do have that added in the ios fastlane folder in the gem file but in the gemfile.lock the plugin is missing and android it is in the gemfile.lock file so i don't know what exactly is different here

Comment: Did you install fastlane via brew?
Have you tried to update fastlane?
Have you tried deleting a fastlane file, creating new a new one and manually creating lanes (maybe you have some invisible characters)?

Comment: Yes, I installed fastlane according to their documentation. It is in the latest version currently. Yes I have deleted it and re init the fastlane for the ios. Can invisible characters make not find the appicon?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Eg. a zero-width space character.

Comment: is there a good way to find out those spaces?